# angaulr index.html# close tag issue

Tags: angular

Created new Angular 6.0.8 project and created static folder by using below command.

```
ng build --prod --base-href . --deploy-url ./static/
```

after create static folder in `index.html` getting dynamically created style link tag with out close.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/styles.e960c4bce55b7f71eeba.css">
```

while try to run application getting below exception, for mean while we have to close link tag manually.

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing
>   document: template="index", line 19 - column 74

Please let me know how to get link with close tag.

Thank you

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC7Zj.png)

Comment: The link and meta tags are not supposed to have closing tags...

Comment: but if its not have close tag it will throwing exception while run application like HTTP status 500, I think its working fine in angular older version may be issue with new version .

Comment: Probably some bug inthe thymeleaf exception - whatever that is.